# Wrong answer on COL_NAME statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a problem with that statement

```
SELECT GENDER 
FROM tableName 
WHERE (SELECT COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('[tableName ]'), 5)) = 'M'
```

It should return all the GENDER from the table where the sex is equal to M
But it returns nothing!

This is the same select but with 'classical' parameters

```
SELECT GENDER 
FROM tableName 
WHERE GENDER = 'M'
```

I also tried using a variable, but with the same blank result!

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @var = (select COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('[MD_PRODUCT].[TABSOURCE]'), 5))
SELECT GENDER FROM MD_PRODUCT.TABSOURCE WHERE @var = 'M'
```

I need to use the COL_NAME (or in alternative the COLUMN_NAME of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA) because whole the parameters in the select are generated dynamically...

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

I'm working with SQL Server in SSMS

Comment: I wouldn't expect that query to return anything. `COL_NAME` returns a *string* with the column's name.

Comment: You are comparing the literal column name `'GENDER'` to `'M'` which is always false. This does NOT grab the value in the `GENDER` column. Your second query `GENDER = 'M'` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? What is the *actual* problem that you want to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all i found the solution with the help of GMB answer.
Here is the correct code:

```
DECLARE @columnName varchar(75)
DECLARE @tableName varchar(75)
declare @sqlCommand varchar(75) 
SET @columnName = (select COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('tableName'), 1))
set @tableName = 'tableName'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' +@columnName+ ' FROM ' +@tableName+ ' WHERE ' +@columnName+ ' = 1'
print @sqlCommand  --just for print out the the sql command variable @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for dynamic SQL. You need to prepare your query in a string and use `EXEC()` to run it.

Consider:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnName varchar(75)
SET @columnName = 'foo'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT GENDER FROM tableName WHERE  ' + @columnName + ' = M'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world are you using COL_NAME here??? You should reference the column.

```
SELECT GENDER 
FROM tableName 
WHERE GENDER = 'M'
```

Comment: i already said it... because table name and column name are generated with dynamic sql... so i cannot declare as usual!

Comment: Then simply use dynamic sql.